# Changing report header textbox value from user input when winform application running

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports to display invoice from a sale. I want to change the report header textbox manually. Means, i have a form named as Crystal report settings. I have a textbox in there to change report header. I have a textbox object in crystal reports. When i add a value in textbox in crystal report settings form and clock on change it should change the value in textbox object in crystal report permanently. I am using it to allow shops to change header details. is there any way to achieve it? How can i permanently get values in textbox object of crystal report from user input?

Crystal Report Text Object is shown below

[image: Crystal Report Text Object]

From the textbox shows below i want to get values for textbox object in crystal reports

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to save your caption/Header of report within database and fetch from there, it will reduce the complexity.
If you insist on using the form, then pass the changed caption/Header value to the form of crystal report through constructor or global variable approach. create a property within your change caption/header form, set its value and get it within your crystal report form and set it i.e.

```
((TextObject)reportDocument.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Invoice_HeaderText"]).Text="Changed Header";
```